# Disk Issues moving from Ubuntu To Windows

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, windows, disk

recently I have been having issues when trying to format an old laptop and move it over to windows to give to a family member. I had the laptop running ubuntu previously. However when trying to run windows installation media no disk is detected to install to even in diskpart. In ubuntu the disk management displays this,

[image]

If anyone knows how to correctly wipe, format the disk so that windows can recognise it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove Ubuntu and put Windows back on?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/133533/how-to-remove-ubuntu-and-put-windows-back-on)

Comment: Unfortunately no since I can not find resources on how to make the disk being used in ubuntu recognised by Windows

Comment: The Windows does not understand partition format `ext4` used by Ubuntu. You may boot from an Ubuntu live USB drive and delete the partition `/dev/nvme0n1p3`. This will remove the Ubuntu partition, but keep the Ubuntu boot-loader in the "EFI System Partition" (ESP).

Comment: I just tried loading up a live usb, deleting the partition and either leaving it as free space or creating a new partition with FAT or NTFS but neither get detected by windows on the setup menu instead saying no drives could be found

Comment: I am out of ideas.

Comment: FIX - Sorry i forgot to close / respond to this but I found out I needed to edit my SATA interface in bios to fix this

Comment: You may want to write an answer to your question by clicking on the "Answer your own questin" button below. Please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-answer) section of the site help before answering the question. Finally do not forget to accept your answer as correct by clicking on the gray check mark next to your answer and turn it green. This will help others.